# Backbone not responding to routes

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I must be losing it.  I've set up the simplest Backbone app, but can't seem to get routes to respond.  Here's my router (in coffeescript):

```
class BackboneSupport.Routers.TicketsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: ->
    @tickets = new BackboneSupport.Collections.TicketsCollection()

  routes:
    "/new"      : "newTicket"
    ".*"        : "index"

  newTicket: ->
    alert 'hi, from the new ticket route'

  index: ->
    // just to prove a point
    $('#tickets').html('tickets go here')
    @navigate('/new')
```

And I get the whole train moving with:

```
<div id="tickets"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.router = new BackboneSupport.Routers.TicketsRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

As you would expect, the root route (index) populates `#tickets` with placeholder text and successfully navigates to the /new route (confirmed via the address bar), however, it does not alert anything, meaning the `newTicket` method is not being triggered.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Per rjz below, I updated the navigate method to:

```
@navigate('/new', {trigger: true})
```

But strangely, still no alert :/

Comment: Yup. you'll want to pass the trigger option as true to make navigate call `newTicket`. See http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate for details :-)

Comment: Hah!  Thanks.  See my update, as it still doesn't fire the new route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have the leading slash in your route, you want this:

```
class BackboneSupport.Routers.TicketsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    "new": "newTicket"
    ".*" : "index"
  #...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/veSDF/1/

From the [fine manual](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-extend):

> **extend** `Backbone.Router.extend(properties, [classProperties])`
>
> [...] Note that you'll want to avoid using a leading slash in your route definitions: